# Is there a natural way to generalize paths and cycles?

Tags: graph-theory

Intuitively, it makes sense to consider paths and cycles as the most simple connected and $2-$connected graphs, respectively. What is the most simple $n-$connected graph?

I didn't define what is this 'simplicity' and am not sure how to, but I thought of something that looks elegant:

- The smallest connected subgraph containing two given vertices of a larger connected graph is always a path.
- The smallest $2-$connected subgraph containing two given vertices of a larger $2-$connected graph is always a cycle.

Asking only for a smallest $n-$connected subgraph kinda works for the cycle, but not for the path (you'll always be given a single vertex), so the two given vertices are there to fix this.

So my question is: Can we describe what kind of graph can be the smallest $n-$connected subgraph containing two given vertices of a larger $n-$connected graph? Should I ask for more given vertices to get an interesting result? Maybe less, treating the path as an anomaly? Or is there a better way to describe how paths and cycles are simple?

I've noticed a trend for $3-$connected graphs: the minimal ones seems to be the ones made of two layers, being one a cycle and the other a vertex, path or cycle, such that every vertex in one layer is connected to some vertex of the other.

[image]

However, if the inner layer is a path, this might not yield a $3-$connected graph and, if it is a cycle, it might yield a $4-$connected one, so there must be additional conditions.

[image]

I would really like to know what is the most simple $\infty-$ connected graph.

Comment: You may find Tutte, A theory of 3-connected graphs, available at https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82624113.pdf to be helpful. "This paper is concerned with those graphs which are both simple and $3$-connected. The central problem is that of determining the simple $3$-connected graphs of $m + 1$ edges when those of $m$ edges are known."

Comment: If your German is up to the challenge, there's also R. Halin, Untersuchungen über minimale $n$-fach zusammenhängende Graphen, Math. Ann. 182, 1969, 175–188, and W. Mader, Minimale $n$-fach zusammenhängende Graphen mit maximaler Kantenzahl, J. Reine Angew. Math. 249, 1971, 201-207.